# azure nodejs website/webapp supported crypto algorithms for JWT token generation and verification

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, jwt, express-jwt

I am developing a nodejs app deployed as a azure website. I am using JWT tokens for authentication using [jws](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). This uses node crypto module underneath.

I created a self-signed RSA256 certificate and have uploaded these files with my app. The app creates the jwt token using the private key without a problem. But when it validates jwt token from a client request, it fails throwing the following exception;

> Exception Details:
>   System.IdentityModel.SignatureVerificationFailedException: IDX10503:
>   Signature validation failed. Keys tried:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey

Azure uses [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode), for iis-node integration. When I run this locally on a windows 2008 R2 server, my application verifies the token without any issues.

I ran a test javascript file via command line node, through visual studio online editor, to test token creation and verification. This test worked fine, which indicates the actual host is capable of handling the decryption.

My questions;
1) Has anyone used JWT on a azure node JS app?
2) Have you come across this exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share you app or your azure website name so we can investigate?

Comment: Hi @RanjithRamachandra unfortunately I can't disclose the application name as I am under NDA. Can you give me some pointers to look at in order to find the root cause? It would be good if the exception was more detailed other than the above. What would be the ideal log file to look at to get the relevant information on azure?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solve this. I had to do two things to solve this.

1. Disable the azure AD authentication I had on for the site.
2. Remove password protection for RSS private key. The certificate is used only in the backend. So this is fine.